# Multipart uploading selected video file to the server in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, alamofire, multipart

I tried to select file using UIImagePicker. But when I tried to upload file using `Alamofire` multipartFormData it gives following error

> "multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartURLInvalid(assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=00178364-C308-4D2F-9B06-ECFBF21B9128&ext=MOV))"

Method use to get file url

```
func selectVideoFromLibrary(sender: Any) {

     let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? NSURL

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

`Alamofire` upload to upload file to server

```
 func uploadVideo(){

        let serverURL = AppConfig.BASEPATH + AppConfig.UPLOAD

        print("upload link is",AppConfig.BASEPATH + AppConfig.UPLOAD)

        let vURL = self.videoURL! as URL
        let vName = videoName.data(using: .ascii)
        let pName = name.data(using: .ascii)
        let pNo = phoneNo.data(using: .ascii)


        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                multipartFormData.append(vURL, withName: "uploadedfile")
                multipartFormData.append(vName!, withName: "title")
                multipartFormData.append(pName!, withName: "pname")
                multipartFormData.append(pNo!, withName: "phoneno")

        },
            to: serverURL,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                        print(response.result.value)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        })

    }
```

Comment: same issue facing by me . can you please update any answer

Answer (score 1):

using info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] to get file url(file://...) instead of the assets-library path will sovle your problem.

as the following code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```